# Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK to my android app, can it report the exception of unity?

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, crashlytics

The Android project I exported in unity introduced firebase Crashlytics, can it report exceptions in unity? If I import firebase Crashlytics in unity and the Android project exported by unity, will this cause any problems?

Answer (score 0):

If you added the Crashlytics Unity SDK in your Unity app, and then export it to Android, crashes happening in the Unity app will be reporter. Adding Crashlytics again into the the app could create issues or conflicts.

Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8XH4b0rOQA), it has detail explanation on how the Crashlytics Unity SDK works.

If your use case is different, please provide more information.